# How to reshape a vector to make a matrix?

Tags: matlab

Here is what I have:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

And here is what I want to get:

```
[
  1,  2,  3,  4,
  5,  6,  7,  8,
  9, 10, 11, 12
]
```

The number of rows and columns (3 and 4 in example) is already known.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [guide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/comm/ref/vec2mat.html) says

> mat = vec2mat(vec,matcol) converts the vector vec into a matrix with matcol columns, creating one row at a time. If the length of vec is not a multiple of matcol, then extra zeros are placed in the last row of mat. The matrix mat has ceil(length(vec)/matcol) rows.

Comment: Note! This requires the "Communications System Toolbox". The "correct" answer is `reshape`. `reshape(vec,[], matcol)` will reshape the vector into a matrix with `matcol` columns. The number of rows is calculated automatically by MATLAB when reshaping.

Comment: The reshape solution also has better performance (at least for square matrices that I tested).

Answer (score 5):

[reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html)

`b = reshape(a, 4, 3)'` will would work for your example. Elements are taken from the original and inserted into the new matrix column-wise.

Furthermore, `reshape` is a built-in MATLAB function. There exists other solutions such as `vec2mat` that require the communications toolbox.

Comment: Are you sure? "given a vector input, reshape creates a matrix one column at a time instead of one row at a time."

Comment: @chx that's why I did 4 rows, 3 columns and transposed the result. I like your answer too, I think they both work.

Comment: oh sorry I missed the transpose.